# How to remove PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server error (don't what to use X11 forwarding)

Tags: linux, x11, putty

Hi whenever I ssh into my Linux machine via Putty, and edit text files via emacs, I get the following warning/error.

'''
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
Display localhost:11.0 unavailable, simulating -nw
'''

How do I remove this warning? I think this arose because, a long time ago I tried and failed to do X11 forwarding. However I don't want to do this anymore and using bash in Linux works for me. So how do I reset Putty/Linux's settings so that this error gets removed? I can't remember what I did in the past so I'm concerned if I had screwed up my Putty/Linux somewhere. Thanks!

Updates

- One suggestion is to disable X forwarding in putty, however I have already done it (picture below)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to disable X forwarding in putty? See e.g. the picture in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/119908/327880).

Comment: Thanks =) yes its disabled but I still get the error (shall put in picture in my original qn above)

Comment: Check proxy and tunnel settings. But also your .ssh/authorized keys: you can add options together the key. Possibly you added some forward/x11 setting there

Comment: Did you disable X11 forwarding in PuTTY also in your saved session (if you connect to the server using a saved session), or only in default parameters?